# MIPS mul and div

Tags: mips

Is it possible to have the same functionality within a MIPS instruction set with add and sub instead of the mul and div instructions? i.e. just add to multiply and subtract to divide?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at a significant performance cost (since multiplication & division are defined in terms of multiple adds & subtractions, respectively) as you'll need whole routines to do what these "missing" instructions do.